# node.js Lambda only runs once (all subsequent attempts fail)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

My lambda attempts to do the following:
Given a particular object in S3: unzip it on the fly, and parse some text (UUID) out of it.

My issue is that it only works once. Here's my code

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const gzip = require('zlib').createGunzip();
const s3 = new aws.S3({region: 'us-east-1', apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const bucket = event.bucket;
    let key = event.key;

    let uuid = '';
    try {
        uuid = await getUuidFromFile(bucket, key);
    }
    catch (err) { console.log("Error!!", err) }

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(uuid || {message: `Failed to retrieve UUID for ${deviceName}`})
    }

};

function getUuidFromFile(bucket, key) {
    let string = '';
    let uuid;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.getObject({Bucket: bucket, Key: key})
            .createReadStream()
            .pipe(gzip)
            .on('data', (data) => {
                string += data.toString();
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                uuid = parseUUID(string.substring(0, 150));
                console.log("UUID", uuid);
                resolve(uuid);
            })
            .on('err', (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
    });
}

function parseUUID(data) {
    // do some actual parsing on the data and get the uuid
    return "uuid";
}
```

When I deploy my lambda and run it for a particular key - it works: finds the file, unzips it, parses it, and returns UUID. Any subsequent runs for the SAME key return absolutely nothing.

Comment: How are you running this Lambda function? Do you get CloudWatch Logs for each invocation of the Lambda function? Did you add logging to the function to try to work out why it's failing to return the expected result?

Comment: @jarmod I'm running the lambda function by using the test functionality. I submit the same payload - works the first time, but fails the next attempts. The CloudWatch logs are available, but are not reporting anything (all lambda runs marked as succeeded). I've sprinkled `console.log` every other line, and all I managed to figure out is that it gets into the `getUuidFromFile` function, but no other log statements are shown.

Comment: Strange. As an FYI you can issue a ranged get if you just want the first 150 bytes of an object. That will save you unnecessarily reading the entirety of a very large object.

Answer (score 1):

I think figured it out.

Before:

```
const gzip = require('zlib').createGunzip();
...
s3.getObject({Bucket: bucket, Key: key})
        .createReadStream()
        .pipe(gzip)
```

After:

```
const zlib = require('zlib');
...
s3.getObject({Bucket: bucket, Key: key})
        .createReadStream()
        .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
```

That's all! Now it works perfectly every time. I suspect this has to do with [Lambda execution environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html), perhaps? Either way, having `createGunzip()` declared at the top, rather every time I call the function, was the issue.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Lambda function warm starts don't re-run the initialization code in your source module; they re-use the previous runtime environment and then simply invoke the function handler. So any 'global' variables retain their value as at the end of the previous invocation of the Lambda function.